# What is the Dual curve to a straight line defined projectively as x+y+z=0?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, duality-theorems

I have recently been learning about algebraic geometry and came across this question in "Algebraic Geometry A Problem Solving Approach" by Thomas Garrity et al. His problem 1.12.18 asks about the dual curve to a projective line given by $L=\{(x:y:z)\in \mathbb{P}^2:ax+by+cz\}$ and why it might be strange.

When I try and answer the question on my own following the recipe on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_curve I get $X=Y=Z=\lambda$, which doesn't make sense to me.

I also looked at the Plücker formula, which I think is saying that a degree 1 curve should have a degree zero dual.

Does anyone have any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dual of $x+y+z=0$ is the point $(1:1:1).$

Your link says: “The dual of a line (a curve of degree 1) is an exception to this and is taken to be a point in the dual space (namely the original line). The dual of a single point is taken to be the collection of lines though the point; this forms a line in the dual space which corresponds to the original point.”

But as you can interpret $ax+by+cz=0$ as a line in the plane, changing the roles of coefficients and variables it’s also the equation of a line in the dual plane. This is the universal line.

Comment: Ahh! Thanks for the answer! I totally missed that on the wiki page. I was also curious about the computational aspect. Could I take the partials as before and compute it? Or does that formalism not work in this case because of the degree being 1?

Comment: @Sora8DTL $X,Y,Z$ are the coefficients, and you've found that the dual is $(\lambda : \lambda : \lambda).$ But that is just $(1:1:1)$ since we can get rid of a common factor in homogeneous coordinates.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much that helped a lot!